# Tkinter Listbox "spacing" between character

Tags: listbox, tkinter

How can I make the Tkinter Listbox from this
[image]

to looks exactly like this:
[image]

Is there any way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a monospace-font like `Courier New`